# How do I solve $\int\limits_C(x^2+y^2)\,\mathrm{d}x+(x^2-y^2)\,\mathrm{d}y$?

Tags: calculus, line-integrals

Here's the integral:

$$\int\limits_C(x^2+y^2)\,\mathrm{d}x+(x^2-y^2)\,\mathrm{d}y$$

Where:

$$\begin{cases}y=1-|1-x| \\ 0\le x \le 2 \end{cases}$$

The integral itself seems easy, but I am more confused about how to deal with module inside the function.

Comment: Is it a closed loop? Does it also have the boundary condition $y>0$?

Comment: @AlgorithmsX,  no, there's nothing about $y$ itself

Comment: And by module, what are you referring to?

Comment: @AlgorithmsX, well, I do not know how to handle it here, for example I remember that indefinite integral has something like $$\int|x|\,\mathrm{d}x=\int x\cdot\mathrm{sign} x\,\mathrm{d}x$$ for just module

Comment: By module, do you mean modulus or absolute value?

Comment: @edm, modulus, otherwise I would just take absolute value inside the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ y=\begin{cases} x&\text{ for }0\le x<1\\
  2-x&\text{ for }1\le x\le2\end{cases}$$

$$ dy=\begin{cases} \phantom{-}dx&\text{ for }0\le x<1\\
  -dx&\text{ for }1\le x\le2\end{cases}$$

\begin{eqnarray}
\int\limits_C(x^2+y^2)\,\mathrm{d}x+(x^2-y^2)\,\mathrm{d}y
&=&\int\limits_{C_1}2x^2-(x^2-x^2)\,\mathrm{d}x+\int\limits_{C_2}(x^2+(2-x)^2)-(x^2-(2-x)^2)\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=&2\int\limits_{C_1}x^2\,\mathrm{d}x+2\int\limits_{C_2}(2-x)^2\,\mathrm{d}x
\end{eqnarray}

Where $C_1$ is the portion of the path where $0\le x<1$ and $C_2$ the portion where $1\le x\le2$.

Comment: Seems expanded and clear enough, only one question, how did you get appropriate differentials?

Comment: The values for $dy$ on the two intervals follow from the values of $y$ immediately above.

Answer (score 1):

Break it up as the integral over two curves $C_1$ in which $0\le x\le 1$ and $C_2$ in which $1\le x\le 2$. Then $\int_C=\int_{C_1}+\int_{C_2}$.

Answer (score 1):

If you graph $y = 1-|1-x|$, you'll see that it's two line segments of different slopes attached at $x=1$.  One way to attack this is to write $C = C_1 \cup C_2$, where $C_1$ and $C_2$ are the two line segments.  Then we can take advantage of the fact that $\displaystyle \int_C \text{ stuff } = \int_{C_1} \text{ stuff } + \int_{C_2} \text{ stuff }$.

Wee can parametrize $C_1$ as $\alpha_1(t) = (t, \ t)$ for $0 \leq t \leq 1$, so $\displaystyle \int_{C_1} (x^2 + y^2)\ dx + (x^2-y^2)\ dy = \int_0^1 2t^2 \ dt$.

Do something similar for $C_2$, compute the integrals, and sum.